# BGR to YCrCb resulting in gray images in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm converting a BGR image to YCrCb and saving it in the disk; however, the output images are gray, how can I save the images to disk with color?

Here is just an example of how my code looks like:

```
Mat img = imread("...");
Mat img2;
cvtColor(img, img2, CV_BGR2YCrCb);

vector<Mat> planes;
split(imgColorConverted, planes);

imwrite(".../planes1.jpg", planes[0]);
imwrite(".../planes2.jpg", planes[1]);
imwrite(".../planes3.jpg", planes[2]);
```

When I open the saved images, it is gray. Is it possible to save the images as the following example that I found on Wikipedia ([Wikipedia - YCbCr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr))?:

Thank you!

[image: Image extracted from Wikipedia]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you case, you save 1 channel pictures, so it's gray. In fact, what you should do is:

```
Mat img = imread("...");
Mat img2;
cvtColor(img, img2, CV_BGR2YCrCb);

vector<Mat> planes;
split(imgColorConverted, planes);

Mat* planes2 = new Mat[3];
Mat emptyMat(planes[0].size(), planes[0].type(), Scalar(0));
Mat Cr, Cb;
imwrite(".../planes1.jpg", planes[0]);
// Set Cr channel on R channel
planes2[0] = emptyMat;
planes2[1] = emptyMat;
planes2[2] = planes[1];
merge(planes2, 3, Cr);
imwrite(".../planes2.jpg", Cr);
// Set Cb channel on B channel
planes2[0] = planes[2];
planes2[1] = emptyMat;
planes2[2] = emptyMat;
merge(planes2, 3, Cb);
imwrite(".../planes3.jpg", Cb);
```

Comment: You could try to do: Mat emptyMat(planes[0].size(), planes[0].type(), Scalar(255));. You will perhaps get better visual results. (White is beautiful :)